# How to make a button to a new form

Tags: c#, wpf

I am looking for help making a button of which will take me to a new form. For example :

[image]

I want the continue to home button to take me there. I have this code so far :

```
private void Click_Home(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BlankPage1 Click_Home = new BlankPage1();
    BlankPage1.Show();
}
```

This doesn't work, it underlines .Show as an error and says :

> BlankPage1 does not contain a definition for 'Show'

Any ideas please?! I have been looking for ages

ALL OF BlankPage1 CODE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace The_Brightside_Clan_Official_Application
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
    {
        public BlankPage1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

My MainPage Code:

```
private void Click_Home(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BlankPage1 Click_Home = new BlankPage1();
    Click_Home.Show();
}
```

Comment: `Click_Home.Show()`, call the method on the instance not the Type.

Comment: what is `BlankPage1`? the error is saying that it has no `show` method... When you say take me to a new form do you mean redirect?

Comment: what framework are you using? It looks like wpf.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between classes and variables.

Comment: .xaml it says not sure though

Comment: @user3411623 Everyone has tried to help and have been correct.  You need to post the code for `BlankPage1` if you want further instruction.

Comment: @user3411623 is your Button Click event getting fired at all?  (Put a break point next to `BlankPage1 Click_Home = new BlankPage1();` then run the program and click the button.  Does it stop in the debugger at your line?

Comment: I posted an answer that may help given the new context.

Comment: Indeed - you're talking about showing a new form, but BlankPage1 isn't a Form, it's a Page.

Answer (score 5):

The code should read

```
private void Click_Home(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BlankPage1 blankPage= new BlankPage1();
    blankPage.Show();
}
```

You're attempting to invoke `Show` on the type instead of the instance.

Comment: I changed it to that but nothing happened?

Answer (score 2):

BlankPage1 is the name of your class. Click_Home is the name of the variable containing an instance of that class. BlankPage1.Show() would be equivalent to code like, say:

```
string demo = "asdf";
MessageBox.Show(string); // you wouldn't expect this to work - you would want to Show(demo);
```

The correct statement would be: `Click_Home.Show();`

If your class BlankPage1 implemented a *static* method called `Show`, calling BlankPage1.Show() would work. That's why it's telling you that it can't find the method, rather than just telling you that you can't call methods on class names directly (you can, if they're static methods).

Comment: I am still not sure what to do :/

Comment: Then should probably post all the code for BlankPage1. We can't tell you why your form isn't doing anything when Shown, from the code you posted; we can only tell you why you were getting that error message (because you were trying to Show() the class, rather than an instance of the class.)

Comment: Ok I will edit my post now!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up your frameworks.  You have a `Page` object (`BlankPage1` inherits from `Page`) not a `Form` or `Window`.

There is no `Show()` method in the `Page` class that I could see.

[System.Web.Ui.Page Definition on MSDN (ASP.Net)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[System.Windows.Controls.Page Definition on MSDN (WPF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So your method should probably look more like this:

```
private void Click_Home(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService navService = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this); //Create a service to nagivate between pages
    BlankPage1 blankPage= new BlankPage1(); //Instantiate your page
    navService.Navigate(blankPage);
}
```

That being said I think you probably just have the wrong base template here.  You probably want a `Window` not a `Page`.

Pages require a `Frame` or something similar to display them.  Windows can be shown, hidden, closed etc...

Comment: How do I create a service to navigate between pages?

Comment: put `using System.Windows.Navigation` in your class...  Then copy/paste.

Comment: Ahhh Thanks I'll do that. I'm new :p

Comment: I put it in and it underlines Navigation and says the type or namespace name 'navigation' does not exist in the namespace 'System.windows'

Comment: You really should just consider making a new *window*, rather than using a `Page`.  Is this WPF or ASP.Net?

Comment: I think it is WPF. I am using windows 8 studio express 2013. It is different to the tutorials on the internet. All i done was add>new item>blankpage. I want a whole new page though as it will be my main home slide.

Comment: Try doing add>new item>window instead.  Then you can call `Click_Home.Show()`.

Comment: There is no item in the presets such as a window :/

Comment: Trying not to add these too fast :)